# What are some good/cheap Data Obfuscation and Data Masking tools?

Tags: obfuscation, data-masking

I am looking for a Data Masking tool to protect the sensitive data/files when I move them to dev environment (all data sits on S3). Is there anybody here that already doing data protection using third party tools? I would appreciate for the recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [FileMasker](https://www.dataveil.com/filemasker/). It supports masking CSV and JSON files on S3. FileMasker can run as an AWS Lambda and can also run on local computers too. A free Community license is available. Disclaimer: I work for the developer.

Answer (score 0):

As you move data onto your development environment, you can have the data published an SNS topic, and have the topic mask the sensitive data for you, in real time.

This data protection feature was first introduced to SNS in September 2022 in public preview, and announced as generally available (GA) in November 2023. This feature supports sensitive data auditing, blocking, masking, and redaction.

For more information, check these out:

- SNS developer guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-data-protection.html
- AWS compute blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-message-data-protection-for-amazon-sns/